# .NET TCPListener limitation?

Tags: .net, client, tcplistener

I have a question about the usage of TCPListener in .NET... I am thinking about a client/server application and being new to this kind of application I have search a bit around the web and the solution which come the more often is to create a new thread for each new client connection.

This solution seem fine but I was wondering if it was still usable with a application where you can have thousands of client at the same time ?

Of course if there is thousands of client the application will not be hosted on a small desktop but on a real server, but is it the way to design an application for a large number of client ?

Thank for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If i'm making an application (server - client), my first thought is always WCF. From experience i've never had any issues with number of clients connecting.

Here are a few links that might introduce you to it, if you don't know it.

1) [MSDN Windows Communication Foundation is...](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa663324.aspx)

2) [MSDN Windows Communication Foundation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119(VS.90).aspx)

I've made a post a while ago concerning wcf, and there's a sample setup of a server. That might help you.

--> [How can i initialise a server on startup?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2697762/how-can-i-initialise-a-server-on-startup)

Comment: Yes I haven't think of it, but as I am not limited with the Framework version it could be a good idea to use this. I will read this now cause I don't know it.